# How can I get multiple skus (with images) but only use one base sku

Tags: configurable-product, custom-options

This is a bad title (feel free to modify it).

I have 75 unique SKUs, lets think of them as socks. Theres 3 different styles, 4 different heal colors, and 5 different body colors. I could probably pick a better example, but whatever. Everyone wears socks.

As you can see, they're all socks so the material, weight, cost, etc is all the same. Only the  image changes. I could create one configurable product and 75 simple products, but that still seems excessive.

If I didn't need an image, custom options would be a no brainer. But since I do, that won't really work. Even if I could attach an image to a custom option, I would still need logic to combine the chosen options into a calculated image.

This is probably a rant, more than anything, but has anyone run into this before? If I should just create the 75 SKUs, let me know if you suggest that.

Thanks

Comment: when you fetch the collection of product then you can filter with sku and put like query

Comment: Keep within the magento infrastructure, you will have less issues, and less complications later on. 75 unique SKUs = 75 unique products, it does not matter that they  all have the exact same properties. Create them, and use a configurable to group them.